# Is it possible to deobfuscate this string of obfuscated Lua Code?

Tags: lua, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have a(nother) string of lua code that's obfuscated. I'm wondering if it's possible to deobfuscate it, or to figure out how it was obfuscated, as I've never encountered anything like it before. This string of code is supposedly the main module for a malicious serverside script executor. Knowing what's inside will help us patch the exploit on our platform. I'm told that it would be easy to decipher by getting the constants, because it's VM based obfuscation, we just need a bit of help getting pointed in the right direction.

The code is rather large, so it's in this pastebin.

pastebin com/dtfzBPZk

Comment: Just like your other post, this one is similarly obfuscated, but with Synapse Xen instead of Luraph, so it's not quite as trivial to deobfuscate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deobfuscating this one looks like it will be a slightly more manual process. As usual, the first things you should do are rename variables to have saner names, and add whitespace and indentation to the code. You can see a start to this at https://pastebin.com/eRTGAbTH. Once you do that, you'll see a pattern of functions like this:

```
(function(...)
    local SynapseXen_116 = "hi xen doesn't work on sk8r please help"
    local SynapseXen_092 = SynapseXen_100(38909278, 3932326132)
    local SynapseXen_069 = {...}
    for SynapseXen_109, SynapseXen_043 in pairs(
        SynapseXen_069
    ) do
        local SynapseXen_119
        local SynapseXen_097 = type(SynapseXen_043)
        if SynapseXen_097 == "number" then
            SynapseXen_119 = SynapseXen_043
        elseif SynapseXen_097 == "string" then
            SynapseXen_119 = SynapseXen_043:len()
        elseif SynapseXen_097 == "table" then
            SynapseXen_119 = SynapseXen_100(4264903821, 30110892)
        end
        SynapseXen_092 = SynapseXen_092 + SynapseXen_119
    end
    SynapseXen_140[1171393165] =
        SynapseXen_bit_bxor(
        SynapseXen_bit_bxor(2179831066, SynapseXen_092),
        SynapseXen_bit_bxor(2132161653, SynapseXen_082)
    ) -
        string.len(SynapseXen_116) -
        SynapseXen_139 -
        #{
            2716917292,
            2960928816,
            2092744992,
            3945961999,
            2156388474,
            2523828292,
            534526172
        }
    return SynapseXen_140[1171393165]
end)({}, {}, 14275, 107, "iIIllIIlIIilillilI", "i", 5327, 3211, 14382, 14643)
```

Now you can start to eliminate red herrings. For example, any time you see `#{ a bunch of stuff in here }`, you can just count the elements in the list, and replace the whole thing with the count. In this case, there's one of those near the end we can replace with the number 7. Next, look at `SynapseXen_116`. The only place it's used is for its length, so you can substitute that in as well. Now,  After that, notice that this is declaring a function and then immediately invoking it, so you can substitute in its arguments. Continue going down that path until you uncover the heart of the Lua-in-Lua VM, and from there, it should be easy to plug in the Base64 at the end, and see what bytecode it decodes to.